# Python: Explicit For Loop, Numpy Sum, Numpy Dot have Different Results

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
NV = np.sum(A[:, 0]*A[:, 1])
V = np.dot(np.reshape(A[:, 0], (1, -1)), A[:, 1])

EFL = 0
for i in range(len(A[:, 0])):
    EFL += A[i, 0]*A[i, 1]
```

where the `A` is a two dimensional array. So basically, I am multiplying two columns of `A` element-wise and then adding the results, and I am expecting that these three methods have the same results. However, the results are very different.

For the non-vectorized `NV`, the result is `1.7763568394002505e-14`, the vectorized `V` is `2.22599716e-14`, and the explicit for-loop `EFL` is `9.272096979096034e-14`.

I have tried multiplying a column of `A` by itself, effectively an `A[:, 0]^2`, and the results are almost the same, `1107.1945737348647`, `1107.19457373`, and `1107.1945737348658` for the `NV`, `V`, and `EFL`, respectively.

Another test that I did was to perform the same calculation (i.e. the different columns of `A`) in Microsoft Excel, and that too gives a different result (around `2.10e-13`). Another strange thing that I encountered was that the results are almost the same up to the second last element of `A`, and they become different once I include the last element. I have checked the last element of `A` and is no different from the other numbers in the array. What could be wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

Here is the link to the matrix A: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16bmI3lg8-2pUntmxtLiaE0cAuvMfhjcj/view?usp=sharing

The numpy version I am using, if it is somehow related is 1.19.2.

Comment: I just tested it with my own `A` (`A = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)`) and found the answers to be `540`, `[540]`, and `540`, respectively. You perhaps need to share the actual values that you have in `A`, or some minimal subset thereof that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Since `A` is a 2-D array, it is not clear what you mean by "second last element of `A`"

Comment: Also, please share the `dtype` of `A`

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Here is `A`: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16bmI3lg8-2pUntmxtLiaE0cAuvMfhjcj/view?usp=sharing. I apologize for the confusion, what I meant by the second last element of `A` is similar to `A[:(len(A[:, 0]) - 1), 0]`, and `A` is a numpy array with each element as a numpy.float64.

Comment: Unable to access the google drive link, perhaps due to insufficient privileges. It is more appropriate to share this info as part of your posted question, by editing it. If that array is too big, it is preferable if you can identify a minimal slice of `A` that can reproduce the discrepancies, and then share the data in that slice as part of your edited question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have edited the restrictions for the link and I have edited the posted question. I have been slicing the array where this error occurs, but it seems to be unreproducible until all elements are accounted, so I have posted the whole array.

Comment: I used your original `A` with its `1980` rows. The values I got for `NV`, `V`, and `EFL` were `0.014003191000011128`, `[0.01400319]`, and `0.014003190999985465`, respectively, which are quite close to each other. and quite different from the results you have posted in your question. Hence unable to reproduce your problem.  :-(

Comment: I get the same numbers as the OP for NV and EFL on two different computers (a Macbook (Intel) and a Raspberry Pi 4). For V, I get different values on the two machines, none of which is equal to the OP's value. And `math.fsum(A[k,0]*A[k,1] for k in range A.shape[0])` gives me yet another values (same on both machines). "Floating-point inaccuracy" sounds like a probable bet for a high-level explanation. I noticed that the sum excluding the last row is almost exactly the negative of the last row. Sounds like a recipe for catastrophic cancellation.

Comment: FYI, I get OP's numbers on Win10 Intel i5 CPU for `NV` and `EFL`.  However, `V` is `2.59237e-14`.   As an extra test I did all three methods in Matlab and the results were consistent and matched OP's `EFL`value.

Comment: For what it's worth, the results that I mentioned above (without any major discrepancies), were obtained using `python=3.7.9`, and `numpy.version.version=1.19.2`, on a Win10 running on AMD A8-7410 APU processor

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. For perspective, my code was processed in an iMac Intel Core i5 and I re-processed it in a Windows 10 Intel Core i7, which had a totally different result than my original post. I am starting to lean on the "Floating-point inaccuracy" suggested by @TurePålsson, and I wonder if I can use the machine epsilon as a parameter to somehow decrease this inaccuracy.